# Java-EE6: Does InitialContext really needs to consume 228 MB of memory?

Tags: jakarta-ee, memory, glassfish

I'm currently developing a 3-tiered application with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 / MySQL 5.5 and a stand-alone Swing client written in Java SE 6. I use JNDI to look-up references to my enterprise beans on the Glassfish application server. For this purpose I initialize an InitialContext:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
```

This line consumes 228 MB of RAM. Is this normal or is there a way to optimize that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it might be loading up the entire `javax` package.

Comment: Yes, a great part is loaded by gf-client.jar. Having look into the MANIFEST.MF of gf-client.jar, reveals that more than 30 additional libs are referenced by the classpath defined within the manifest file... Are these all necessary?

Comment: Maybe not, but are you really going to modify the `javax` package to load up only those libs you need, when entry level for a computer nowadays is 4 gigs? :)

Comment: I really need to optimize memory consumption for my application, since other parts of it, consume additional 550 MB... finally ending up with 800 MB :-( This kills machines with only 2GB of memory, since the OS usually consumes another 1-1.5GB...

Comment: Whatever the number and size of the jars are, and the size of the javax package is, it doesn't have any relationship to the amount of memory used. If a class is not loaded, it doesn't use any memory. Else, every class in compressed rt.jar of 58 MBs would be loaded each time a one-line program is executed. If the memory is used, then it means that many classes are actually loaded from the jars (if it's the available permgen space which decreases), or that many objects are instantiated (if it's the available heap space that decreases)

Comment: does perhaps exist a more light-wighted approach to communicate with Glassfish from the perspective of a stand-alone client?

Comment: Well, just because the line of code says that memory consumption goes up by 228 MB doesn't mean that memory is acutally being used, but only allocated.  If you're committed to javax, I would wait and see if it actually becomes a problem.

Comment: I already got OutOfMemoryExceptions while testing on my Ubuntu 11.10 test machine with 3 GB of memory. That's why I started this thread. Many thanks for your answers so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the stand-alone client on a 32-bit JVM reduces memory consumption down to 54 MB. [Here's an article discussing this issue.](http://www.1060.org/blogxter/entry?publicid=1F0377DE37DD6705BE96CC2BC27FEA19)